# I can't clear the markers from the jquery-bing-maps

Tags: jquery, bing-maps

I'm trying to clear the map.

The function provided by the page of the project (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-bing-maps/) is not working:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
```

I've tried to do it manually:

```
var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map');
for (var i = map.entities.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var entity = map.entities.get(i);
        if (entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection ){
            alert(map.entities.get(i).getLength());
            for (var j = map.entities.get(i).getLength() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                map.entities.get(i).removeAt(j);
            }
            alert(map.entities.get(i).getLength());
        }

        if (entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin || entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Infobox ){
            map.entities.removeAt(i);
        }
    }
```

but when i do this, i ask for the length of the entities and apparently the markers are gone, but when i try to render new markers the old ones appear again.

How can i rid out of the first set of markers?

I'm initializing the map like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
    credentials: "My credentials",
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-8, -80),
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye,
    customizeOverlays: true,
    showBreadcrumb: true,
    zoom: 4,         
    showDashboard: false,
    showScalebar: false,
    showCopyright: false,
    showMapTypeSelector: false
};

$('#map_canvas').gmap(mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution, idk if is provisional:

I modified the jquery.ui.bmap.js clear method like this:

```
/**
 * Clears by type
 * @param type:string i.e. markers, overlays, services
 */
clear: function(type) {
    this._c(type);
    this.set(type, []);
},

_c: function(obj) {
    for ( var property in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(property) ) {
            if ( obj[property] instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin || obj[property] instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Infobox || obj[property] instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Map ) {
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(obj[property]);
                this.get('map').entities.remove(obj[property]);
            } else if ( obj[property] instanceof Array ) {
                this._c(obj[property]);
            }
            obj[property] = null;
        }
    }
    if (obj == 'markers'){
        for (var i = this.get('map').entities.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var entity = this.get('map').entities.get(i);
            if (entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection ){
                for (var j = this.get('map').entities.get(i).getLength() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

                    this.get('map').entities.get(i).removeAt(j);
                }
                this.get('map').entities.removeAt(i);
            }

            if (entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin || entity instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Infobox ){
                this.get('map').entities.removeAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

},
```

So, if i call the markers clears the if clausule is activated and i remove the entityCollections of the map, i think the problem is the clear is not properly removing the layers so if you try to remove the pins from the map you will be able to do it but when the view changes the pins will appear again in the map because you remove the pins but the layer is still there and has the previous config (specifically the _data[] in the module http://www.bingmapsportal.com/Scripts/V7ClientSideClustering.js)